# select data from array in array index

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, loops, indexing

This is datas returned from MYSQL :

[Datas from MYSQL](http://arthur.ochin.free.fr/data.JPG)

In javascript I need to put in a `var` (separated by a coma) all string from "niveau" but i don't know how i can select "niveau" in different [index] from "Chapitres" and [index] from "Videos"... with a loop ?

I tried something like that ... :

```
var NIV = "";
$.each(e.valeur_tableau_infos_tutoriel.Chapitres[].Videos[].niveau, function  (index,value){
NIV += value.NIV+',';
```

How can i select each "niveau" in each [index] of my arrays ? knowing that it can have xx index...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do nested `$.each`es

```
var NIV = [];
$.each(e.valeur_tableau_infos_tutoriel.Chapitres, function (idx, chapitre) {
    $.each(chapitre.Videos, function (idx, video) {
        NIV.push(video.NIV);
    });
});
NIV = NIV.split(',');
```

Comment: it seems to be good but with a consol.log, i have an error "[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]" ...

Comment: @user3484934 based on the MySQL data you showed us maybe it's `video.niveau` instead of `video.NIV`

Comment: Same error :( "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function "

Comment: @user3484934 just make sure that everything is spelled correctly and log things out as you go.  What line do you get `undefined is not a function` for?

Comment: I put a consol.log at the end of your code and it returns this "undefined is not a function" for this line "NIV = NIV.split(',')"

Comment: A found the solution : i just convert my array in string with that : "var NIV = NIV.toString(); "